# Synonym request for 'jax-rs'

Tags: support, synonym-request

Currently I see two tags [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) and [jaxrs](/questions/tagged/jaxrs). I propose to merge [jaxrs](/questions/tagged/jaxrs) to [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [currently synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jax-rs/synonyms). So, they are already merged.

Comment: Nitpicking: Being synonyms doesn't mean that they are merged.  A merge is a one-time operation when the synonym is created that *retags* questions.  You can create a synonym without merging the tags.